# Usage of for loop in python

Tags: python

I have created a script that gets the `href` link from inside an anchor tag, along with the text.

Here is my python code:

```
import re
import cssselect
from lxml import html

mainTree = html.fromstring('<a href="https://www.example.com/laptops/" title="Laptops"><div class="subCategoryItem">Laptops <span class="cnv-items">(229)</span></div></a>')

for links in mainTree.cssselect('a'):
    urls = [links.get('href')]
    texts = re.findall(re.compile(u'[A-z- &]+'), links.text_content())

    for text in texts:
        print (text)

    for url in urls:
        print (url)
```

Output:

```
Laptops 
https://www.example.com/laptops/
```

Instead of using two for loops can I do this?

```
for text, url in texts, urls:
    print (text)
    print (url)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: @NathanielFord I get this: "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack".

Comment: I think this is a bit of an XY problem. The question you're asking about combined loops is indeed answered by `zip` as described by @kmad1729. However, I don't know why you're looping at all. You'll only ever have one URL per `<a>` tag, and so I suspect `zip` won't do what you want if you get multiple hits on your `re.findall` search (all but the first result will be ignored). Perhaps you just want to filter out inappropriate characters from the string returned by the `text_content` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine what you're trying to do here:

```
for text, url in texts, urls:
    print (text)
    print (url)
```

The `text, url` part right after the `for` indicates 'unpack the [tuple](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) indicated after `in` into two parts'. If the tuple doesn't have two parts you'll get a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html).

Both of the lists you're iterating through have single values, and simply putting a `,` between them won't do what you're looking for. As suggested in another answer, you can [`zip`](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) them into a single array:

```
for text, url in zip(texts, urls):
    print (text)
    print (url)
```

What zip does is return a list where each element is a tuple comprised of one element from each of the provided lists. This works well, but doesn't solve the problem of not looping through your list twice: you're still doing that, once for zip  and once to unpack the zip. Your deeper problem is *how* you're getting your values.

You seem to be stepping through each link you have, and then *for each link* you are getting the url and the text and putting it into a list. You're then printing everything in those lists. Do those lists ever have a length greater than one?

The [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html) function will only return a single value:

```
urls = [links.get('href')]  //Gets one value and puts it in a list of length one
```

Putting it into a list there is not meaningful. As for your regex search, it could in theory return multiple values, but if you use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html), then you'll only get the first match and don't need to worry about additional values. This is what you're currently doing:

```
for each link in the document
  put the url into a list
  put all the matching text into a list
  for each url in the list print it
  for each text in the list print it
```

When really you can simplify to:

```
for each link in the document
  print the url
  find the first text and print it
```

Then you don't have to worry about the additional for loops and zipping. This refactors to:

```
for links in mainTree.cssselect('a'):
    print(links.get('href'))
    print(re.search(re.compile(u'[A-z- &]+'), links.text_content()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
for text, url in zip(texts, urls):
    print (text)
    print (url)
```

What it does is *zips* two or more iterables. They need not be of the same size either.

```
>>> l1 = range(5)
>>> l2 = range(6)
>>> list(zip(l1,l2)) #produces
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
>>>
```

Comment: `zip` is a great function! Note that here it is overkill and doesn't actually reduce the computational complexity.